# How can I generate n points with euclidan distance less than d from X

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

Let's say I have a point:
`point <- c(1, 2)`
How can I generate 10 points with euclidan distance from `point` lower than some choosen value, e.g. 3.
In other words: how can I generate set of points in my point's neighbourhood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is randomly choose a distance between 0 and 3, then a direction between 0 and 360. Do this with desired precision:

```
r <- 3 * sqrt(runif(10)) ##Since area increases proportionally to distance, as pointed out in comments
theta <- 2 * pi * runif(10)
```

To get the coordinates:

```
x <- point[1] + r * cos(theta)
y <- point[2] + r * sin(theta)
```

Comment: To sample from a continuous space, you should do: `r <- 3 * runif(10)` and `theta <- 2 * pi * runif(10)`.

Comment: To sample uniformly from the area, you should do `r <- 3 * sqrt(runif(10))`. Plot the results with `n = 10000` under each method to see how untransformed uniform `r` oversamples the center.

Comment: @shujaa Another good point - area should be sampled not distance from center.